# IDistributedCache with Redis cache performing atomic operations

Tags: .net, .net-core, redis

.Net Core and IDistributedCache with Redis (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1). How does one perform atomic operations when using IDistributedCache with Redis?
I want to make sure I do not overwrite any values in cache if many different users connect to two different endpoints and run redisCache.Set() command at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this useful and it seems to do what I want:
https://redis.io/topics/distlock, more specifically: https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net

**Registration:**

```
services.AddSingleton<IDistributedLockFactory, RedLockFactory>(x =>
            RedLockFactory.Create(new List<RedLockEndPoint> { new DnsEndPoint(options.Host, options.Port) }));
```

**Usage:**

```
public RedisCache(IDistributedCache cache, IDistributedLockFactory lockFactory)
{
    _cache = cache;
    _lockFactory = lockFactory;
}

public async Task<T> GetOrAddAsync(string key, Func<T> createItem)
{
    ...
    using (var redLock = await _lockFactory.CreateLockAsync(key, _expire, _wait, _retry))
    {
        if (redLock.IsAcquired)
        {
            // do stuff here
            _cache.Set(.....);
        }
    }

    return cacheEntry;
}
```